# Making a cylinder from a plane

Tags: modeling

I want to make a plane as the shape for a cylinder object and then turn that into a cylinder. This can be done by extruding, which can also be used for straight objects like skirting borders.

But extrude+rotate for a cylinder is a lot of steps (number of sides for the cylinder) and requires cleaning up of some "internal" faces and duplicate vertices, I also got some faces with flipped normals for some reason. Is there a built in operation to do this?

[image: The Plane]
[image: The Cylinder]

Example scene with the two objects:
[image]

Comment: can you attach your file here  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so that answer will go in little detail

Comment: Of the plane? sure, will do once back. But nothing special about it, and if say a ring of vertices on a 2D plane without faces or such is a better option then that works as well

Comment: @atek added an example file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several solutions, like the *Spin* tool or the *Simple Deform* modifier (with *Bend* option), or the *Curve* modifier, but I guess the **Screw Modifier** is the easiest way:

- Create your profile shape, without any inner face. Keep in mind that the origin of the object will be the pivot of the rotation.
- Assign your object a *Screw* modifier, choose the good axis, choose a 360° angle, and as many Steps as you want.
- Keep a copy of your object before applying the modifier. Recalculate the Normals if necessary (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> in Edit mode). You can also choose not to apply the *Screw* modifier, it will just make the edges sharpening a little bit longer at the end.
- Assign your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. On the left panel (<kbd>T</kbd>) click on *Tools* > *Shading* > *Smooth*.
- In *Edit* mode, add some edge loops to make your edges sharper (or, if you didn't apply the modifier, create some new vertices close to the existing ones: Select an edge, then create a vertice with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*, then move the vertice along the edges with *G G* until it comes close to one of the existing vertices).

[image]

Comment: That looks like a far better tool for the job :) Is it needed to apply the modifier to fix up the normals? Could be useful to keep it just as modifiers.

Comment: it looks like it makes the things more complicated, yes, especially to make the edges sharper. If you want to keep the modifiers, you should use another method I guess (I've cited several others).

Comment: I was thinking of adding the extra edge vertices before (see the picture of the plane). I'll take a look at the others as well as not tools I have used so far.

Comment: for the Simple Deform and Curve modifiers you first need to extrude your profile, so it's not exactly the same method but you get the same sort of result. The Spin tool is fast but it is destructive (modifier = non-destructive).

Comment: Actually I've tried without applying the Screw modifier and it works fine, it just takes a bit longer to create vertices close to the existing ones in order to create sharp edges.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also but no more control later you can have it.

Press <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>  to Right Ortho

In Edit mode -> Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Spins)

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to increase decrease the steps and the angle.

[image]